# Python: How can I print bytes?

Tags: python, binary, python-2.x

I'm using Python 2.7.

I want to print a binary in decimal, but I'm receiving an error, which I do not understand.

Eg. I am trying:

```
print 0b111
```

I am expecting 7. But it returns:

> Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/print line 528.
>   Error: no "print" mailcap rules found for type "text/x-python"

Can you help? Just a beginner with Python!

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: code `print 0b111` works for me on Python 2.7 - so maybe you have problem in different place. Or maybe system doesn't know that you run Python code - you have to add in first line `shebang` - `#!/usr/bin/env python` - probably now it treats this code as bash script and it runs command `/usr/bin/print` - see error message.

Comment: Are you sure your code goes to the Python interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... at /usr/bin/print ...

Sounds like you're invoking the script incorrectly. Either use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) that points to a Python executable or explicitly pass it to the executable.

```
python somescript.py
```